# Linux commands to get Latest file depending on file name

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to linux. I have a folder with many files in it and i need to get the latest file depending on the file name. Example: I have 3 files `RAT_20190111.txt` `RAT_20190212.txt` `RAT_20190321.txt` . I need a linux command to move the latest file here `RAT20190321.txt` to a specific directory.

Comment: This is off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it

Comment: @talonmies This is a shell script programming question, so it is on-topic here.

Comment: Is the format of your file names fixed, i.e. always `RAT_` followed by 4 digits year, 2 digits month and 2 digits day, followed by `.txt`? You seem to have forgotten the underscore in the latest file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file pattern remains the same then you can try below command :

```
mv $(ls RAT*|sort -r|head -1) /path/to/directory/
```

As pointed out by @wwn, there is no need to use `sort`, Since the files are lexicographically sortable `ls` should do the job already of sorting them so the command will become :

```
mv $(ls RAT*|tail -1) /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Since the files seem to be lexicographicaly sortable ls should do the job already of sorting them i.e.: you can save one pipe ;-): ```mv $(ls RAT*|tail -1) /path/to/directory```

Comment: @wwn You are correct actually. I didn't realize that there is no need to sort. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pacifist: parsing output of `ls` might not be a good idea: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

The following command works.

ls | grep -v '/$' |sort | tail -n 1 | xargs -d '\n' -r mv -- /path/to/directory

The command first splits output of ls with newline. Then sorts it, takes the last file and then it moves this to the required directory.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command

cp `ls |tail -n 1` /data...